# Prevent user from zooming Tkinter window

Tags: tkinter

I am coding a GUI app in python Tkinter on macOS. I used this to place a button:

```
 tk.Button(...).place(x=...,y=...)
```

At first, the button will be placed in the middle. But when I zoom the window, the button looks very small and it is not at the middle anymore. So how can I stop user from zooming the Tkinter window? Thanks

Comment: To stop the user from resizing the window use: `<tk.Tk>.resizable(False, False)`. Also I would suggest making your widgets expand as the window is resized.

Comment: if you are using place and want the widget to always be centered you can try: `.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')` but really it is rare to use `.place`, better use `.pack` or `.grid` because you can solve most problems with those two and they are more "dynamic"

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you so much. Post your comment as an answer and I will verify it

Comment: Instead of preventing the user from zooming the window, the better solution is to design your GUI so that it is resizable. For example, with `place` you can use relative positioning so that it is always in the middle of the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah but I don't like anyone to zoom it out. The buttons are small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this. See root.resizable(False, False)

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('')

# SETTING THE APP SIZE AND LOCATION ON THE MONITOR
app1_width = 1480
app1_height = 960
mon_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
mon_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (mon_width / 2) - (app1_width / 2)
y = (mon_height / 2) - (app1_height / 1.8)
root.geometry(f'{app1_width}x{app1_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
root.resizable(False, False)
```